# How to make the syntax of String.format recognisable in IDEA?

Tags: java, string, intellij-idea, string-formatting

I have

```
String.format("%smultiple/%s", a, b);
```

It's `"%s"`, `"multiple/"`, and `"%s"` concatenated.

[image]

I write in IntelliJ IDEA and I am looking for a way to help the IDE recognise the pattern and not show

> Typo: in word 'smultiple'

I scrolled through the options in "Inject language or reference" and didn't find anything particularly useful.

I looked up a plugin - nothing.

Comment: Have you tried [adding the word to the dictionary](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spellchecking.html#saving_word)? Personally, I find the idea of spell-checking string literals silly. They often contain format instructions, commands and whatnot.

Comment: @GhostCat nice one :) Our questions are different, though. Yours is more about a mundane task no one would like to do, mine is about a nuisance I find hard to ignore/correct. I don't want to split the template.

Comment: @RealSkeptic next time I write *smultiple* in java docs or name a variable that way, it will say the spelling is correct and I will miss a real typo.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like [this bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-26761) to me. Given that was filed 10 years ago, I wouldn't hold my breath for a fix!

If you can't live with just ignoring it, split the literal:

```
String.format("%s" + "multiple/%s", a, b);
```

or move the `multiple` into the args:

```
String.format("%s%s/%s", a, "multiple", b);
```

Comment: I was thinking about it, and I'd rather not. My whole point of using `String.format` is to not use concatenation. Otherwise, I could have written `a + "multiple/" + b`.

Comment: And we can't report this as a bug :( It seems they don't have this functionality at all. At least, I haven't seen any highlights in `String.format`...

Comment: It's a bug, and it won't likely be fixed, but you can (and should) do option B; it would allow you to localize this if needed, and would use the correct platform tools. As already stated, the concatenations are managed by the compiler and will likely result in the same bytecode.

Comment: Actually, @AndrewTobilko, the _first_ form of concatenation is harmless, as the compiler will already eliminate it.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini: Option B is actually quite a bad option for l10n, as it contains built-up grammar and very short strings (often a source of wrong translations).

Comment: @MichaelPiefel I was talking about using a localizable pattern: `%smultiple/%s` should be in a String and it should be `String.format(R.string.whatever, a, b);` (that's how I would do it)

Comment: @MichaelPiefel I'd say any concatenation on a small scale (like this) is harmless. It's more about readability and declaring the original intention. Also, this template can be refactored to a constant one day...